# php echo not echoing in order

Tags: php, echo

I am trying to echo these variable in order

```
$caption = "Some random caption";
$url = " https://example.com";
$tags = " tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4 ";
$message = $caption.$url.$tags;
```

and the output is not in order. it is like this

`tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4 Some random caption https://example.com`

The actual code looks like this:

``

```
function hashtag($string){
   $newString = str_replace(' ', "", $string);
         $nString = str_replace(',', " #", $newString);
echo $nString;
}
$name =  "Full Name";
$hashName = " #".str_replace(' ', '', $name);
$string = ', tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5, tag6, tag7';
$tags = hashtag($string);
$url = ' http://example.com';
$caption = ' some random caption';
$message = $caption.$url.$tags;
echo $message;
```

Comment: Can you show the actual code which echos out the strings.

Comment: `$url` is not set in your `$message`, do you output `$Url` somewhere after that?

Comment: As @kerbholz alludes to, PHP is case-sensitive for identifiers

Comment: Is your HTML language direction set to right to left? ex: <html dir="rtl" lang="ar"> This comes to mind as to why text appears backwards when it is echo'd. As others said, make sure it's either always $Url, or $url - otherwise you have an undeclared variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `echo` your hashtags in the function, so that string is displayed at the moment you call it. Your function don't return anything, so the value of `$tags` is NULL and the tags don't appear in the second `echo`

Use a `return` statement in the function to solve your problem :

```
function hashtag($string){
    $newString = str_replace(' ', "", $string);
    $nString = str_replace(',', " #", $newString);
    return $nString;
}
```